# Python 3 chokes on CP-1252/ANSI reading

Tags: python, unicode, latin1, cp1252, python-3.x

I'm working on a series of parsers where I get a bunch of tracebacks from my unit tests like:

```
  File "c:\Python31\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 112: character maps to <undefined>
```

The files are opened with open() with no extra arguemnts.  Can I pass extra arguments to open() or use something in the codec module to open these differently?

This came up with code that was written in Python 2 and converted to 3 with the 2to3 tool.

UPDATE: it turns out this is a result of feeding a zipfile into the parser.  The unit test actually expects this to happen.  The parser should recognize it as something that can't be parsed.  So, I need to change my exception handling.  In the process of doing that now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Position 0x81 is unassigned in Windows-1252 (aka cp1252).  It is assigned to U+0081 HIGH OCTET PRESET (HOP) control character in Latin-1 (aka ISO 8859-1).  I can reproduce your error in Python 3.1 like this:

```
>>> b'\x81'.decode('cp1252')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

or with an actual file:

```
>>> open('test.txt', 'wb').write(b'\x81\n')
2
>>> open('test.txt').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 0: unexpected code byte
```

Now to treat this file as Latin-1 you pass the `encoding` argument, like codeape suggested:

```
>>> open('test.txt', encoding='latin-1').read()
'\x81\n'
```

Beware that there are differences between Windows-1257 and Latin-1 encodings, e.g. Latin-1 doesn't have “smart quotes”.  If the file you're processing is a text file, ask yourself what that \x81 is doing in it.

Comment: FWIW Latin-1 has all 256 codepoints assigned, so you'll never get a UnicodeDecodeError.  But you might corrupt your data.

Answer (score 5):

You can relax the error handling.

For instance:

```
f = open(filename, encoding="...", errors="replace")
```

Or:

```
f = open(filename, encoding="...", errors="ignore")
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#open).

**EDIT:**

But are you certain that the problem is in reading the file? Could it be that the exception happens when something is written to the console? Check http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

Comment: I tried both of these with the same results.  The error is thrown before output happens.

Comment: -1 "relax the error handling" with no clue as to what is being ignored or why -- mindless butchery

Comment: Indeed, ignoring encoding errors is bad practice and violates the Unicode standard.

Comment: @altie: The error is probably from writing something to the console.

Comment: thank you, this was very helpful.  My situation was that I have text logs with very occasional binary data, and I wanted to regex and process them.

Answer (score 2):

All files are "not Unicode". Unicode is an internal representation which must be encoded. You need to determine for each file what encoding has been used, and specify that where necessary when the file is opened.

*As the traceback and error message indicate*, **the file in question is NOT encoded in `cp1252`.**

If it is encoded in `latin1`, the `"\x81"` that it is complaining about is a C1 control character that doesn't even have a name (in Unicode). ***Consider `latin1` extremely unlikely to be valid.***

You say "some of the files are parsed with xml.dom.minidom" -- parsed successfully or unsuccessfully?

A valid XML file should declare its encoding (default is UTF-8) in the first line, and you should not need to specify an encoding in your code. Show us the code that you are using to do the xml.dom.minidom parsing.

"others read directly as iterables" -- sample code please.

Suggestion: try opening some of each type of file in your browser. Then click View and click Character Encoding (Firefox) or Encoding (Internet Explorer). What encoding has the browser guessed [usually reliably]?

Other possible encoding clues: What languages are used in the text in the files? Where did you get the files from?

Note: please edit your question with clarifying information; don't answer in the comments.

Comment: It's possibly a DOS code page, in which '\x81' is usually 'ü'.