# Python : split text to list of lines

Tags: python, text, split, lines

am new to Python , But i have text File like :

```
12345 | 6789 | abcd | efgh
```

i want my output be Like :

```
12345
6789
abcd
efgh
```

=====================

i really don't know the script 
but i made a lot of scripts  by those function split() , strip() , blame blame blame

but i failed to do it 
so am asking for help is someone can .

i will appreciate any Help .

```
with open('contacts_index1.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines("|")
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting the question exactly?

Comment: The real code is: `f.readlines()` then loop over them all splitting on '|'

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\findme.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 529: character maps to <undefined> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all of your comments, it looks like the issue has to do with the actual text in the file, and not the ability to parse it.  It looks like everyone's solution in here is on the right track, you just need to force the encoding.

The error you are describing is described [in this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character).

```
with open('contacts_index1.txt', 'r') as f:
     lines = f.read().encode("utf-8").replace("|", "\n")
```

EDIT: The issue appears to be a nasty character that wasn't properly decoding. With `open` you can tell it to ignore characters it can't decode.

```
import io 
with io.open("contacts_index1.txt", errors="ignore") as f:
    lines = f.read()replace("|", "\n")
```

Comment: u r right bro .

but it still gave me the same error , i don't have no idea . what can i do !

Comment: i also saved the file as "UTF-8" and the error is still appear

Comment: Try the solution in that link.  The error you show has it loading with encoding "CP1252".  So there has to be a way to force it to read with a different encoding (like utf-8).

`import io`
`io.open('contacts_index1.txt', encoding="utf-8")` OR `io.open('contacts_index1.txt', encoding="latin-1")`

Comment: Another option is to tell Python to throw out the character if it can't decode it: `io.open("contacts_index1.txt", errors="ignore")`  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284827/python-3-chokes-on-cp-1252-ansi-reading

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use decode. The following code will work:

```
def dataFunction(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
        return f.read()
```

Call this function with filename as parameter:

```
Contents = dataFunction(filename)
elements = Contents.split("|")
for element in elements:
         print(element)
```

Comment: am sorry , i didn't understand what exactly suppose i do ?

Comment: am sorry again , but it gave me that :


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\hope.py", line 4, in <module>
    Contents = dataFunction("contacts_index1.txt")
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\hope.py", line 3, in dataFunction
    return f.read().decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 529: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Check out i have updated! If not works comment...! I would like to help you!

Comment: If it not works check encoding="Latin-1"  event that also does not work check the encoding format using online tools and change the second argument it will work...! @SamehWeangy

Comment: i already did , and the upper error which i commented back is  appeared ,
am really appreciate what u trying to do bro .

Comment: Remove that decode function..! Except is thrown on that decode function..!

Comment: Also if you want to check your file encoding use this https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projects/chared/ tool .

Comment: Up vote that comment so that users will get to know..! Welcome

Comment: i already did bro , but it says something like less than 15 Reputations cant vote .

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with the code you posted:

- `f.read` doesn't read the whole line. It should be `f.readline()`.
- What is the function `splitlines`?

Your question is pretty unclear in differnt aspects. Maybe this snippet could be of some help:

```
for line in open('contacts_index1.txt'):
    elements = line.split('|')
    for element in elements:
        print element.strip()
```

Editted: I didn't know the function `splitlines`. Just looked it up. The way you used it in your code doesn't seem to be correct anyway.

Comment: and your code gave me that error 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\csvfind.py", line 1, in <module>
    for line in open('contacts_index1.txt'):
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 529: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: am sorry i meat line.split()

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using csv module for this kind of task, as it seems like a csv-type file, using '|' as delimiter:

```
import csv
with open('contacts_index1.txt','r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        #do things with each line
        print "\n".join(row)
```

Comment: i have tried the CSV also but here's the error 


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\csvfind.py", line 4, in <module>
    for row in reader:
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 529: character maps to <undefined>`

Answer (score 0):

Please do this line by line. There is no need to read the entire file at once.

Something like:

```
with open(file_name) as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        for word in line.split('|'):
            print word.strip()
```

---

If it is a unicode issue, most of the time it is automatic:

```
$ cat /tmp/so.txt
12345 | 6789 | abcd | éfgh
```

(note the `é` in the file)

The program above works. If it does NOT work, use a codec:

```
with open(fn) as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        line=line.decode('utf-8')  # or whatever codec is used for that file...
        for word in line.split('|'):
            print word.strip()
```

---

With Python3, just set the encoding when you open the file:

```
with open(fn, encoding='utf-8') as f_in:   # <= replace with the encoding of the file...
    for line in f_in:
        for word in line.split('|'):
            print(word.strip())
```

Comment: @dwg thanks , bro  
it's worked with one .
but the another  one have encoding problem . so am still stuck in this problem of decode .

Comment: If it is an encoding issue, just open with a proper codec.

Comment: i made another solution for encoding  with ur script , and now it's worked .
Thank you bro .
but if i need to write the output into new file instead of  printing in the shell  
what should i do , bro ?

Comment: Python 2 or 3? Makes a difference. Python 2, use `encode` and `decode` on each end as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17246997/298607). Python 3, use the encoder embedded in [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: it's  python-3.5.0

Comment: Use a proper open statement of encoding. It is transparent at that point