# Encoding Issues when reading .htm files with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to read in a large set of `.htm` files with Python. To do so I am using the following:

```
HtmlFile = codecs.open(file, 'r')
text = BeautifulSoup(HtmlFile.read()).text
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 411: 
character maps to <undefined>
```

So, I tried encoding with `utf-8` like so:

```
HtmlFile = codecs.open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
text = BeautifulSoup(HtmlFile.read()).text
```

And then I got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 4565: 
invalid start byte
```

I tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s), but it was not helping. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `codecs.open()` instead of plain `open()`?

Comment: I thought it would help. I still receive the errors with just open()

Comment: What if you do `text = BeautifulSoup(HtmlFile).text`?

Comment: Sadly that does not help. I included a GoogleDrive link to a sample file above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a bit of research and it's an issue with a Microsoft generated file using the CP1252 encoding, however there are some things that are not picked up correctly. Given the following:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)">
```

in your html file this seems more than likely.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284827/python-3-chokes-on-cp-1252-ansi-reading), if you use Latin-1 encoding for that example it could help:

```
HtmlFile = codecs.open(file, 'r', encoding='latin-1')
text = BeautifulSoup(HtmlFile.read()).text
```

Let me know if this works. Beware that Latin-1 does not have all the characters that the Microsoft encodings have though.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to solve the issue for me. I absolutely hate encoding errors. Not sure why they encoded their files like so.

Comment: Yeah, they're tedious as. This may work in this case but if you're ingesting a heap of websites, you may need to check the encoding and process accordingly. Good luck!